# Why do I get a lint message of ") expected" in WebStorm in a react native project?

Tags: react-native, webstorm, lint

This line of code is correct and it's working well, but it is causes a lint message: ") expected". Are there settings changes I could make to prevent this?

```
state = {selected: (new Map(): Map<string, boolean>)};
```

[image]

Comment: this syntax is valid neither for TypeScript nor for JavaScript, as far as I can see. Please provide the full code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using Flow - this is the only JavaScript dialect that supports static typing (type annotations) + class fields. Please make sure to set `JavaScript Language version` accordingly - choose `Flow` in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript`

Comment: Yes! I'm using Flow. Thank you for answer. It's worked for me